# ¿Cómo obtener todos los días de la semana pasada?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero obtener las 5 fechas de la semana pasada(L-V). Tengo una `tabla1` donde se registran las fechas de lunes a viernes, pero por ejemplo si el martes no hubo registros yo necesito que en el `SELECT` que haga a la tabla me regrese esa fecha pero en resultado `0` o `null` pero que me lo regrese, lo que no quiero es esto Lunes(fecha), Miércoles(fecha), Jueves(fecha), Viernes(fecha) osea aquí falta el martes porque no hubo registros.

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0)
```

Con este select puedo saber donde empieza la semana pasada(fecha) y con el siguiente puedo obtener el ultimo dia(fecha):

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6-2)
```

Independientemente de que si falta una fecha registrada quiero que me regrese las 5 fechas de la semana, como podria hacer esto o alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: Podrías utilizar ISNULL(CONSULTA,0), esto te regresa lo que quieras ya sea 0 o un null solo revisa si el registro es null ponle 0 si no trae el registro es como un ternario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asi es como saque los dias de las semana en que hubo registros en la semana pasada.

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Entrada) AS Fechas,DATENAME(DD,Entrada) AS 
NumDay,CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, SUM( 
DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000',TiempoPiso)),'00:00:00.000'))AS Tiempo
FROM MiTabla
WHERE Nombre = @nombre and ((CONVERT(date,Entrada)  between 
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0))  and  
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6 -2))))
GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Entrada),DATENAME(DD,Entrada)
ORDER BY DATENAME(DD,Entrada) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podrias hacer es una tabla de dias de la semana, y joinearla contra tu consulta, de esa forma, si algo viene null, sabrias que no hay nada.

Dada la tabla DiasSemana

```
nombre   dia
Lunes     0
Martes    1
Miercoles 2
Jueves    3
Viernes   4
```

Podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
Select s.nombre, t.tusdatos
from DiasSemana s
left join TuQuery t on s.dia = t.weekday
```

De esa forma, siempre vas a mostrar los dias.

Comment: estoy tratando de entender tu respuesta pero no lo consigo, ya tengo la tabla donde registro los dias de la semana, pero ahora el joinearla con mi tabla donde tengo registradas las fechas, me sigue retornando solo las fechas registradas y eso es lo que no quiero, quiero que me regrese las 5 fechas sin importar si hay datos registrados o no.

Comment: Entiendo tu problema @Manny, pero que esperas, que sql cree magicamente datos donde no sabe que hay? mi solucion, te da para toda la semana los dias que vino. Podrias recorrer la tabla resultante y llenar los agujeros a mano. Sql no los puede llenar por vos.

Comment: Bueno no quedo como queria, asi que solo tomo los dias que hubo registros y listo.